# $C^n[a,b]$ as a normed algebra

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, metric-spaces, normed-spaces

I would like to prove that the space of complex valued functions, differentiable $n$ times with continuous derivative, $C^n[a,b]$, with the metric defined by the norm $$\|x\|=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{1}{k!}\max_{a\leq t\leq b}|x^{(k)}(t)|$$ is a normed algebra, but I cannot verify that $\forall x,y\in C^n[a,b]\quad \|xy\|\leq \|x\|\cdot\|y\|$.

Could anyone help me?

Thank you so much!!!

Comment: Rescaling in $t$ gives for any $a>0$ an equivalent algebra norm $\sum_{k}\frac{a^k}{k!} \max |x^{(k)}(t)|$ . Also, the norm works in $d$ dimensions.

Comment: No worries! Btw, there is also the wrong (I think)  one $\max_t( \sum \frac{1}{k!} |x^{(k)}(t)|)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have that
$$
(fg)^{(k)}(x)=\sum_{j=0}^k\binom{k}{j}f^{(j)}(x)g^{(k-j)}(x),
$$
hence
$$
\lvert (\,fg)^{(k)}(x)\rvert\le\sum_{j=0}^k\binom{k}{j }\lvert\, f^{(j)}(x)\rvert\lvert
g^{(k-j)}(x)\rvert\le \sum_{j=0}^k\binom{k}{j }\max_{x\in[a,b]}\lvert\, f^{(j)}(x)\rvert
\cdot \max_{x\in[a,b]}\lvert\, g^{(k-j)}(x)\rvert,
$$
and thus
$$
\frac{\max_{x\in[a,b]}\lvert (\,fg)^{(k)}(x)\rvert}{k!}\le\sum_{j=0}^k\frac{1}{j!(k-j)!}\max_{x\in[a,b]}\lvert\, f^{(j)}(x)\rvert
\cdot \max_{x\in[a,b]}\lvert\, g^{(k-j)}(x)\rvert,
$$
and summing over $k$ we obtain
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{\max_{x\in[a,b]}\lvert (\,fg)^{(k)}(x)\rvert}{k!}\le
\sum_{k=0}^n\sum_{j=0}^k\frac{1}{j!(k-j)!}\max_{x\in[a,b]}\lvert\, f^{(j)}(x)\rvert
\cdot \max_{x\in[a,b]}\lvert\, g^{(k-j)}(x)\rvert \\
=\left(\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{\max_{x\in[a,b]}\lvert (\,f)^{(k)}(x)\rvert}{k!}\right)\cdot
\left(\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{\max_{x\in[a,b]}\lvert (\,g)^{(k)}(x)\rvert}{k!}\right),
$$
which is what we are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

$C^n([a,b])$ is the space of the functions over $[a,b]$ such that $f^{(n)}$ is *continuous* (otherwise, we would not be able the take a $\max$ in the definition of the norm, but just a $\sup$). Anyway,
$$\frac{1}{k!}\frac{d^k}{dx^k}(f\cdot g)=\sum_{j=0}^{k}\frac{f^{(j)}}{j!}\cdot\frac{g^{(k-j)}}{(k-j)!}$$
while:
$$\|f\|\cdot\|g\| = \sum_{0\leq a,b\leq n}\frac{\max |f^{(a)}|}{a!}\cdot \frac{\max |g^{(b)}|}{b!}$$
hence
$$ \|f\cdot g\| \leq \|f\|\cdot\|g\| $$
just follows from the triangle inequality.

Comment: $\infty$ thanks!!!

Comment: @DavideZena: you're welcome.